# What am I doing wrong with preg_replace?

Tags: php, preg-replace

I have fought with this for multiple days now. Im trying to get my preg_replaces working. 
I'm getting the data to use the `preg-replace` on from a database and binding them to variables. `$post_preview` is one of them.

```
<?php
    $body_sub = substr($post_preview, 0) . "<br><br><a href='post.php?id=$post_id'> Continue Reading →</a>";
    echo nl2br($body_sub); ?></p>
            <?php
    //bold
        $post_preview = preg_replace('/(\[bold\])/', '<strong>', $post_preview);
        $post_preview = preg_replace('/(\[\/bold\])/', '</strong>', $post_preview);
        echo '[bold]Test[/bold]';
    //italic
        $post_preview = preg_replace('/(\[i\])/', '<i>', $post_preview);
        $post_preview = preg_replace('/(\[\/i\])/', '</i>', $post_preview);
```

This isn't replacing the `[i]` and `[bold]` nor the `[/i]` and the `[/bold]`. No errors even with `E_ALL`. What have I done wrong and how do I fix it?

Comment: Are you sure you output the correct data? `echo '[bold]Test[/bold]';` seems misplaced.

Comment: Its there just for testing purposes. The correct data is the `echo nl2br($body_sub); ?>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regular expressions have too much brackets (see n0tiz' post) . However this can be much simplified. First of all, I'd suggest to use one regular expression for one tag, not two. This can easily be done via a wildcard like `(.*)?` meaning:

- `(` begin of new group
- `.` every character
- `*` 0 or more times
- `)` end of group
- `?` don't be greedy ([What do lazy and greedy mean in the context of regular expressions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301285/what-do-lazy-and-greedy-mean-in-the-context-of-regular-expressions))

Now since your operations don't have any arguments, in the next part since both operations are the same they should get into one loop, so the code needs to be written only once.

```
$text = "[bold]hello this [i]is a test[/bold][bold]i[/i]";

$html_tags = array(
    "bold" => "strong",
    "i" => "em",
);

foreach ($html_tags as $code=>$tag)
    $text = preg_replace("/\[$code\](.*)?\[\/$code]/i", "<$tag>$1</$tag>", $text);
```

Using one regular expression has the advantage that wrong code won't create wrong HTML.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
//bold
$post_preview = preg_replace('/\[bold\]/', '<strong>', $post_preview);
$post_preview = preg_replace('/\[\/bold\]/', '</strong>', $post_preview);
//italic
$post_preview = preg_replace('/\[i\]/', '<i>', $post_preview);
$post_preview = preg_replace('/\[\/i\]/', '</i>', $post_preview);

echo $post_preview;
?>
```

This should do it. I'm wondering why you'd want to use a regular expression for these though. Wouldn't it be far easier if you'd use [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) in this case?